# Assign zero value to random type use macros in C?

Tags: c, macros

In a macro below, `returnValue` could be any type.

```
typeof(FuncReturnType) returnValue = Func(); \
typeof(FuncReturnType) expectReturnValue = (zero value)
```

`returnValue` could be `int`, `double` `pointer`, `struct` and so on. How can I declare a `expectReturnValue` to be zero value with all these types?

Comment: You could `memset(&expectReturnValue, 0, sizeof(expectReturnValue))`.

Comment: `memset` is not guaranteed to work with pointer, possibly not even `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `= { 0 };` with any type.

For example:

```
int i = { 0 };
double d = { 0 };
struct y { int a; char b; } x = { 0 };
```

You probably can find options to GCC that cause it to complain about missing initializers for `x`, but you have to be trying moderately hard.  The code shown compiles cleanly to an object file when compiled using:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -c xx29.c
$
```

Within the standard, §6.7 Declarations specifies:

> *init-declarator:*
>       *declarator*
>       *declarator* `=` *initializer*

§6.7.8 Initialization specifies:

> *initializer:*
>       *assignment-expression*
>       `{` *initializer-list* `}`
>       `{` *initializer-list* `, }`
>
> ¶11 The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.

This rule is used to initialize `i` and `d`.